# how to Retrieve date from xml file

Tags: php, xml, wikipedia-api

this is my xml file,i do not known how to retrieve value from xml file using php,how to retrieve infromation from the xml file.if you known please help me.

```
  my xml file:
  see:http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?  format=xml&action=query&titles=vikram&prop=revisions&rvprop=content


  <api>
  <query>
  <normalized>
   <n from="vikram" to="Vikram"/>
   </normalized>
   <pages>
   <page pageid="1034501" ns="0" title="Vikram">
    <revisions>
    <rev xml:space="preserve">
    '''Vikram''' may refer to: *[[Vikram (name)]], a male name in the Hindu  
    community *[[Vikramāditya]], a legendary king of India **Vikram, a character
   in   ''[[Baital Pachisi]]'', identified with Vikramāditya **[[Vikram Samvat]]
  (Vikram's Era, "V.S." or "B.S"), a popularly used calendar in India and the 
  official calendar of Nepal, established by Vikramaditya *[[Vikram Pandit]], 
  CitiGroup CEO *[[Vikram (actor)]], Vikram Kennedy, a Tamil-language Indian 
 film actor *[[Vikram Sarabhai]], an Indian scientist *[[Vikram 
 (film)|''Vikram'' (film)]], a 1986 Tamil-language Indian film *[[Vikram (1986 
 Telugu film)|''Vikram'' (1986 Telugu film)]], a 1986 Telugu-language Indian 
 film *[[Vikram Seth]], a bestselling author of Indian origin ;See also: *
 {{lookfrom|Vikram}} *{{intitle|Vikram}} {{disambig}}
 </rev>
 </revisions>
 </page>
 </pages>
 </query>
 </api>
```

Comment: There are a whole bunch of PHP XML APIs you can use. Try [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Comment: i can not understand please give me sample code

Comment: There's sample code on the page I linked. We're not here to spoon feed the code to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the xml_parse_into_struct() function for an easy to parse XML.

```
<?php
$simple = "<para><note>simple note</note></para>";
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $simple, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);
echo "Index array\n";
print_r($index);
echo "\nVals array\n";
print_r($vals);
?>
```

[source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's native [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) or [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: @user1308746: this is not a site for getting people to write code for you.  Please look at the resources that benedict_w has given you and try it out for yourself.  Then if you have questions and issues with what you have tried.  let us know